# relaciones eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent

Bueno con esta consulta logro mostrar los siguiente datos en mi datatables.

```
public function dataTable()
    {
      
        $ordenes = Order::with('client', 'user')->get();             
        return dataTables::of($ordenes)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($ordenes){

                    return $ordenes->id;
                })  
                ->addColumn('n°_orden', function ($ordenes){

                    return $ordenes->num;
                })  
                ->addColumn('fecha', function ($ordenes){                 
                    
                    return   '<i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->date->format('d-m-y');

                })
                ->addColumn('cliente', function ($ordenes){

                    // return 
                    // '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['name_company']."<br>".
                    // '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['phone_company'];

                    return
                        '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client['name_client']."<br>".
                        '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client['phone_client'];
                                   
                }) 
                ->addColumn('operario', function ($ordenes){
                    
                    return 
                    '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->user['name'];                    
                  
                })
              
                
                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['n°_orden', 'fecha', 'cliente', 'operario', 'producto', 'estado', 'accion'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**El inconveniente que se me presenta es que necesito mostrar en la columna cliente el nombre de la empresa y no el nombre del contacto**;
entonces de que manera modifico mi consulta para poder acceder al **nombre de la empresa que se encuentra en mi tabla companies???**
En mi Models Orders no existe esa relacion con companies solo existe la client.
Aca mi modelo client:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name_client','lastname','address','city','province','postal_code','country','phone_client','email'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Company');
    }    

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    } 
}
```

aca mi modelo order:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['num', 'name', 'status', 'date'];

    public $timestamps = true;  

    protected $dates = ['date'];    

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'client_id');
    }   

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }   

    
}
```

pensaba en una relacion anidada

```
  $ordenes = Order::with(['client.company'], 'user')->get();
```

pero tengo problemas al momento de pasar la relacion en esto

```
 ->addColumn('cliente', function ($ordenes){

                    // return 
                    // '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['name_company']."<br>".
                    // '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['phone_company'];

                    return
                        '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client.company['name_client']."<br>".
                        '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client.company['phone_client'];
                                   
                })
```

y recibo un error de sintaxis, a lo mejor existe la posibilidad de agregar un where o alguna otra condicion pero de momento no se me ocurre como hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perdón por responder pero aun no tengo puntaje para comentar
Parece que usas . 
Esto PHP lo entiende como concatenación
Sustituye por

```
$ordenes->client->company['name_client']
```

Comment: Osea con esta consulta  $ordenes = Order::with(['client.company'], 'user')->get(); y corrigiendo lo que me indicas debería de funcionar  luego lo pruebo y comento gracias

Comment: gracias eso funciono para mi!! No se me había ocurrido proceder de esa manera